# create only one instance of a class from outside

Tags: java

I have a class `Class1`. I want to have only one instance of this class.

Now I can do it via Singleton pattern but what I have seen is that in this pattern the class itself manages its own instance; for e.g:

```
public class Class1 {
   private static Class1 INSTANCE;

   // some instance variables...

   // Private Constructor
   private Class1() {...}

   public static Class1 getInstance() {
      synchronized(INSTANCE) {
         if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Class1();
         }
      }
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   public void class1Method1() {
      ...
   }
}
```

and you use its method by

```
Class1.getInstance().class1Method1();
```

But in my case another class `Class2` needs to create the single instance of class `Class1`. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Whatever class calls the method which creates an object instance shouldn't matter if the reference to the created instance is available to either class. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I don't get it. You can call `getInstance()` method from `Class2` to get or create instance.

Comment: Do you want to create only one instance of a class and make sure that only one class has access to it? Otherwise, your question doesn't make sense..

Comment: @bot: Or maybe create a new instance if and only if `Class2` is calling?

Comment: @npinti. Unless the OP wants to allow more classes to get an instance of the singleton, wouldn't it be better to create a private inner class and have a static reference variable to the private inner class instance?

Comment: @bot: I meant create a new instance each time (do away with the singleton). Other classes will pass through the singleton. To be honest I am having a hard time following the question as well.

Comment: @npinti I didn't comprehend your comment correctly. Yes that could a possible requirement as well. And yes, the question doesn't make sense. But part of a programmers job is to understand absurd requirements isin't it?

Comment: @bot: Well, most of us try XD.

Comment: Class `Class1` has some instance variables whose values needs to be setup only once at the time of creation of singleton instance of `Class1`. 

Class `Class2` will be creating the singleton instance of `Class1` and also will be setting up those instance variables of `Class1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the instance of class1 in class2 you can do it by doing this in class2:

Class1 class1Instance = Class1.getInstance();

Hope it helps.